# C# - Read, Split and Extend CSV-file

Tags: c#, list, csv

i am sitting on a problem and i can't find a solution.

I get a performancelog.csv which looks like this as an example.

```
Start;End;Function;Type;Duration
13:37:25;13:37:27;getData();CF;2
13:37:26;13:37:29;initAnything();OS;3
13:37:28;13:37:38;writeData();CF;10
13:37:39;13:37:40;close();OS;1
```

Further i have a file where the current revision number of the build with which this perfomancelog was created is written.

Revision.txt

157

My goal is it to split my existing perfomancelog into 2 Type separated logs with the duration time of the revision. And only functions which took longer than 1sec.

I want 2 files

performancelog_CF.csv

```
Function;Type;Duration(157)
getData();CF;2
writeData();CF;10
```

performancelog_OS.csv

```
Function;Type;Duration(157)
initAnything();OS;3
```

Now when i get a new build and with that a new performancelog i want to extend my existing performancelog_CF and performancelog_OS.

The new performancelog now looks like this:

```
Start;End;Function;Type;Duration
13:37:25;13:37:27;getData();CF;2
13:37:26;13:37:29;initAnything();OS;1
13:37:28;13:37:38;writeData();CF;10
13:37:37;13:37:40;newFunction();CF;3
13:37:39;13:37:40;close();OS;3
```

Revision is now 158

According to this i want my files to look like this:

performancelog_CF.csv

```
Function;Type;Duration(157);Duration(158)
getData();CF;2;2
writeData();CF;10;10
newFunction();CF;;3
```

As you can see the space for newFunction() in the 157-Build should be empty because this function didn't exist there or didnt take more than 1 sec to complete.

performancelog_OS.csv

```
Function;Type;Duration(157);Duration(158)
initAnything();OS;3;
13:37:39;13:37:40;close();OS;;3
```

I hope i was able to show you guys what my goal is. Maybe someone can help me out.

Cheers Shoe

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace perfanalyse
{
    class Filterung
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\path\deploy\local\logs\perflog.csv"))
            {
                List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] values = line.Split(';');

                    list.Add(values);
                }

                string revision = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\path\deploy\binary\svnrevision.txt");        

                list.RemoveAt(0); //removing header
                foreach (string[] arr in list)
                {
                    double d = Convert.ToDouble(arr[2]/*Duration*/, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


                    //Erstellung CF Result
                    if (!File.Exists("C:/path/result_CF.csv"))
                    {
                        using (var file = File.CreateText("C:/path/result_CF.csv"))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine("Category;Plugin;Context;Duration Revision (" + revision + ")");
                        }
                    }
                    else // Erweiterung CF Result wenn Datei bereits vorhanden ist
                    {
                        if (!arr[5].Equals(string.Empty) && arr[5] /*Type*/ == "CF" && d >= 0.05)
                        {
                            using (var readercf = new StreamReader(@"C:/path/result_CF.csv"))
                            {
                                List<string[]> listcf = new List<string[]>();
                                while (!readercf.EndOfStream)
                                {
                                    var linecf = readercf.ReadLine();
                                    string[] valuescf = linecf.Split(';');

                                    listcf.Add(valuescf);
                                }

                                listcf.RemoveAt(0);
                                int i = 0;
                                foreach (string[] arrcf in listcf)
                                {
                                    if (arr[4]/*Function name of perflog.csv*/.Equals(arrcf[2]/*function name of result_cf.csv*/)) //if Funktionsname (Ursprung) equals Funktionsname (neue Datei)
                                    {
                                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:/path/result_CF.csv"))
                                        {
                                            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", listcf[0], arrcf[1]));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:/path/result_CF.csv"))
                                        {
                                            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", arr[5]/*type*/, arr[6]/*plugin*/, arr[4]/*function name*/, arr[2]/*duration*/));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }                         
                        }
                    }

                    //This ist just copy-paste of the CF-part for the result_OS and result_init. Wanted to try if it works on result_cf first

                    //Erstellung OS Result
                    if (!File.Exists("C:/path/result_OS.csv"))
                    {
                        using (var file = File.CreateText("C:/path/result_OS.csv"))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine("Category;Plugin;Context;Duration Revision (" + revision + ")");
                        }
                    }
                    else // Erweiterung OS Result wenn Datei bereits vorhanden ist
                    {
                        if (!arr[5].Equals(string.Empty) && arr[5] == "OS" && d >= 0.05)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:/path/result_OS.csv"))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", arr[5], arr[6], arr[4], arr[2]));
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    //Erstellung INIT Result
                    if (!File.Exists("C:/path/result_INIT.csv"))
                    {
                        using (var file = File.CreateText("C:/path/result_INIT.csv"))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine("Category;Plugin;Context;Duration Revision (" + revision + ")");
                        }
                    }
                    else // Erweiterung INIT Result wenn Datei bereits vorhanden ist
                    {
                        if (!arr[5].Equals(string.Empty) && arr[5].Contains("INIT") && d >= 0.05)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:/path/result_INIT.csv"))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(string.Join(";", arr[5], arr[6], arr[4], arr[2]));
                            }

                        }
                    }                   
                }              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want us to write this code for you? did you put effort on it? we are not your programming guy right?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just asking for solution? It looks like functional requirement not a question to be honest. You need to use some library that can handle CSV files. I can recommend [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: i am sitting on this for the last 4 days. the thing is. i never learned to code and yeah i tried many things. if you guys want to, i can upload my existing code and you cna correct me on this

Comment: @S.Shoe That'd be great. We don't know the exact problem you are facing and what is blocking you. You will learn nothing if someone will just write the entire solution for you,  unless you don't care about learning anything

Comment: I have used the [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) nuget package before for processing multirecord format csv files.  Its got pretty good documentation showing you how to use it. https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/

Comment: i added my code to my OP. hope it helps to clear things up

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: thanks jp i will try that